# Do i need to use broadcast with alarm manager?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

i'm creating an alarm application, and this  is the method to run the alarm :

```
public void startAlarm(int minuteToStart)
{

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Start in " + formatTime(minuteToStart), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteToStart);    
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, idPendingIntent, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

And it run this activity after given specific time:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {
......
}
```

It works, but i see people are using BroadcastReceiver, am i doing it wrong? should i use BroadcastReceiver too? I've been searching about BroadcastReceiver but i don't get what difference it will make with my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the general case, A--C's answer would be correct.

However, you are using `RTC_WAKEUP` as the alarm type. The *only* guarantee that we have with `_WAKEUP` alarms is *if* we use a `BroadcastReceiver`, *then* Android will ensure that the device will stay awake long enough for us to execute `onReceive()`. Any other type of `PendingIntent` -- activity or service -- has no guarantee, and it is very possible for the device to fall back asleep before the `startActivity()` or `startService()` actually occurs.

Comment: So i should use BroadcastReceiver to call the activity.. right?

Comment: @barikatul: Alarm apps are tricky to write, since you have to deal with displaying things in spite of the keyguard. I personally have never tried writing one and do not know all of the issues. And, since the `startActivity()` call made by your `BroadcastReceiver` itself is asynchronous, just using a `BroadcastReceiver` alone will be insufficient. You may need to do stuff like what my `WakefulIntentService` does: `acquire()` a static `WakeLock` in your `BroadcastReceiver`, start the activity, and have the activity eventually `release()` that `WakeLock`.

Comment: @CommonsWare if you want, feel free to merge the relevant parts of my answer into yours, you have the more important information anyways.

Comment: I see, i thought it was simple :D, thanks for the explanation,

Comment: @A--C: I want to give credit where credit is due, and for the non-`_WAKEUP` case, your answer is spot on.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AlarmManager` with whatever `PendingIntent` is capable of (Activity, service, Receiver), though, it is *usually* used with Receivers - taks executing in the future usually are small and don't need an Activity to run in since the user doesn't need something popping up.

A Receiver isn't an Activity, so it does not have a UI and it has a processing time limit of about 10 seconds, so make sure to be quick. If you require a UI to be shown at a specific time, stick with an `Activity`, but usually this isn't the case *unless* it's something like an Alarm Clock app that the user **has** to see). If you have something like a small behind the scenes operation, go for a Receiver. The Receiver's `onReceive()` gets a `Context` passed to it so it can do anything a `Context` can.

Just keep in mind you will have to change the `PendingIntent.getActivity()` call to whatever else you decide to use if it's not going to be an Activity.

So it all depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use a `BroadcastReceiver`. It's just generally frowned upon (in most cases) to steal focus and launch an `Activity` from the background without user interaction. There are certainly valid use cases though. If you intend to launch an `Activity` immediately anyway, doing that directly instead of via `BroadcastReceiver` is perfectly valid.